# How to exclude a value from being counted in a groupby function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
AID  Type        Co-AID   Co-Type
1    A           10       A
1    A           11       B
1    A           12       B
1    A           13       C
1    A           14       D
2    X           15       A
2    X           16       A
2    X           17       X
2    X           18       B
2    X           19       X
2    X           20       X
```

I want to find the percent of Co-Types for each Type that are different than it.

So the result would be

```
  AID  Type   PercentDiff
    1    A    0.8       
    2    X    0.5
```

`0.8` is because 4/5 of the `Co-Type` are not `Type A`

`0.5` is because 3/6 of the `Co-Type` are not `Type X`

I know I can group them according to `Type` and `Co-Type` and get the count of each, but how to exclude the type similar to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
df.assign(PercentDiff=df['Type'].ne(df['Co-Type']))\
  .groupby(['AID','Type'])['PercentDiff'].mean().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   AID Type  PercentDiff
0    1    A          0.8
1    2    X          0.5
```

## *Timings*

@Psidom Method

```
%%timeit
((df['Co-Type'] != df.Type)
  .groupby([df.AID, df.Type])
  .apply(lambda g: g.sum()/g.size)
  .reset_index(name="PercentDiff"))
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 7.13 ms per loop

This method without lambda

```
%%timeit
(df.assign(PercentDiff=df['Type'].ne(df['Co-Type']))
  .groupby(['AID','Type'])['PercentDiff'].mean().reset_index())
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 4.42 ms per loop

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
((df['Co-Type'] != df.Type)
  .groupby([df.AID, df.Type])
  .apply(lambda g: g.sum()/g.size)
  .reset_index(name="PercentDiff"))

# AID   Type    PercentDiff
#0  1      A            0.8
#1  2      X            0.5
```